# Is there an equation to calculate the oscillation frequency with arbitrary forces?

Tags: kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I know that for a harmonic oscillator with a restoring force of $F = -kx$ tke period can be calculated as $T = 2\pi\sqrt {\dfrac {m} {k}}$.

But is there an equation to calculate the period (midpoint and amplitude) for an arbitrary force like $F= m +kx -lx^2$?

Comment: The exact formula for $T$ can be found [here](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~egardi/MfP3-Dynamics/Dynamics_lecture_8.pdf), equation 147.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Now to learn integrals and problem solved! Thank you. :D

Comment: But you do realize that in order to use equation 147, you still have to know $x_a$ and $x_b$...?

Comment: Which I can easily calculate using zero points of velocity.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform could you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @TTkacki you can answer your own question and accept it. It is actually encouraged that users answer their own questions if they come up with a solution. Also, if you make the answer nice and clear you might get a few upvotes :-)

Answer (score -1):

There is no such explicit equation of the period for arbitrary force (potential). You can write the period as an integral over a function of the potential, but you still need to know the amplitudes.

Also the harmonic oscillator is special in that you have a characteristic frequency, dependent on system parameters only and valid for all amplitudes.

In **anharmonic oscillators** that you describe there is no such single frequency. You might want to check out the Duffing oscillator as an example.

PS: The force you give as example implies a cubic potential which can have a local minimum in which you can have oscillations. However since the potential is not bounded (system can escape), this is usually not what you want (but rather add a fourth order term in the potential).